# Can't restore Nexus 6p Google Drive backup to new LG G6

Tags: backup, restore

Previously I've owned Nexus phones and the transfer of apps etc from old to new phone has been seamless. However restoring apps from my old Nexus 6p to my new LG G6 didn't work. The only thing that transferred was the google account.

I'm able to see the N6p backup on Google Drive from a desktop browser, but when I try to restore backups via G6 settings, I get told that no backups are available.

Is the LG maybe incompatible with the Android backup/restore system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar experience with restoring a N6p backup to a Pixel. Nexus was running Oreo and Pixel still on Nougat. After updating Pixel to Oreo and doing a factory reset I was able to restore the N6p backup.

So it seem you can not restore to older Android release, is the LG running older version than the N6p?

Comment: Yeah - don't think the LG has Oreo yet. I've accepted defeat and just installed stuff manually. :)